# Vite start server - Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm getting the following exit 1 code when attempting to launch a server from vite (vue/javascript) for the first time. I've installed the latest versions of vite/vue globally successfully (vue 3.4.21, @vitejs/plugin-vue 5.0.4, vite 5.2.6)

I've tried re-installing node and the postcss-import module thinking that was why the modules were missing, but still get the same message

```
pnpm dev

> thesis@0.1.0 dev /Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive
> vite

failed to load config from /Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/vite.config.mjs
error when starting dev server:
file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/@vitejs+plugin-vue@5.0.4_vite@3.1.8_vue@3.2.41/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:2
import { isCSSRequest, normalizePath as normalizePath$1, transformWithEsbuild, formatPostcssSourceMap, createFilter } from 'vite';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'vite' does not provide an export named 'isCSSRequest'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.1.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:63518:21)
    at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.1.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:63409:28)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.1.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:63026:28)
    at async createServer (file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.1.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:62092:20)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///Users/emilychu/Documents/Personal/archive/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.1.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:700:24)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: this might be useful https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/20413

Answer (score 0):

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'vite' does not provide an export
> named 'isCSSRequest'

suggests that the version of vite you have installed does not export a function or variable named isCSSRequest, which the @vitejs/plugin-vue package is attempting to import.

The problem is most likely that you have mismatch on the compatible versions of `vite` and `@vitejs/plugin-vue`

Easy way to solve this is choose a version of `@vitejs/plugin-vue` that was released a bit after `vite`.

Or you an spend some time and check [change log](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/blob/main/packages/plugin-vue/CHANGELOG.md) for notes on the compatible `vite`

Once you know the working versions, make the changes in package.json and run

> pnpm install

Answer (score 0):

These were all excellent solutions especially since I also believed it was something wrong with the @vigejs/plugin-vue package or the config file but actually running `pnpm -i` and then `pnpm dev` resolved this